# Jquery Add To Calendar Widget

Tags: jquery, calendar

Maybe someone that has experience with the Jquery Add to Calendar Widget (https://github.com/tardate/jquery.addtocalendar) can give me a hand. I have implemented the widget as described in the instructions, but all of the event hours are 4 or 5 hours behind, regardless of the client I use (Google, Hotmail, Yahoo). Even when I try the widget example (http://tardate.com/addtocal/addtocal.htm), the hours are off when it attempts to add to my online calendar. I noticed that that there was an older version of this widget in the example, but the latest version does the same thing. I'm using the hcalendar microformat:

20080928T103000Z

Has anyone had success with this widget lately? I implemented it about a year ago, and it worked (otherwise it wouldn't have been included with the live site). Has something changed with the mail client's API's? Do I have to account for the time zones myself? I've been searching and searching, but I have no idea what may have changed. Thanks for any insight.

Comment: Have you looked at timezones? That script uses the standard Javascript Date library, it doesn't look like the script offer any timezone functionality. You may have to play around with .setUTCHours()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove the Z from the end. the Z forces UTC time, which is not desired when sending a date to an e-mail client.